# How to isolate all data on a per user base in sails.js for ember.js?

Tags: ember.js, orm, ember-data, sails.js, json-api

I wanna build a simple ember app with sails as the backend. 
There are nice [blueprints](https://github.com/mphasize/sails-ember-blueprints) that will help me with that, but I want all data to be complete user isolated. So its actually a single user application, but for multiple users.

So all data is different for each user. So when ember makes a request to `/notes/findAll` I only wanna return the notes corresponding to the user. On the other side a user has full rights on all data that belongs to him (except maybe the user model, which is the only special case).

What is the simplest way to do this?

- I could modify the blueprints itself! But is this a good idea? It would be nice to be able to combine it later by configuration on a per-model-base.
- Is there a way to do this with a policy? So a policy setting a safe user-filter?
- Is there another better/default way to solve my problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am building the same sort of application. I accomplish this by adding an `owner` attribute to every model, and setting it in a policy.

https://github.com/tjwebb/xtuple-api/blob/master/api/models/base/xTupleObject.js#L29-L32

I created `Permission` and `Role` models, and if the object the user is asking for relates to their `User` object via a `Permission` and `Role`, then they are authorized for a particular action.

https://github.com/tjwebb/xtuple-api/blob/master/api/policies/authorize.js#L51-L56

If you want to grant access to the `findAll` method, you might want to re-implement it in a superclass that all your controllers inherit from. I haven't gotten to this part yet, but this is my plan for solving this problem.